# Get parameters from URL in Controller Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, get

I try to submit my form by get method, but then in controller I cant get value, here is controller:

```
  var_dump($request->query->get('startPoint')); // its NULL
```

My form:

```
<form id="s_f" action ="{{ path('trip_search') }}" method="get" novalidate="">
    {{ form_widget(search_form, {'attr': {'class': 'search_form'} }) }}
</form>
```

Generated url:

```
http://example.com/app_dev.php/search_trips?search_form%5BstartPoint%5D=3123123&search_form%5BendPoint%5D=&search_form%5
```

Maybe problem related with this symbols `%5D` in the URL ? Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do like this, if you can't find QS values:

```
var_dump($request->query->all());
```

it shows all QS values;

In your case, you can access your QS data by:

```
$formData = $request->query->get('search_form');
```

or

```
$formData = $request->query->get($form->getName());
```

it returns array of values, after that you can access `startPoints` like this:

```
$formData['startPoints']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write `$request->get('startPoints')` instead of `$request->query->get('startPoint')`

Comment: No you shouldn't! It's way slower. From the PHPDoc: Avoid using this method in controllers: * slow, * prefer to get from a "named" source. It is better to explicitly get request parameters from the appropriate public property instead (query, attributes, request).